# PyQt5 window shrinked after converting from .ui to .py

Tags: pyqt5

I have designed the .ui file in the qt designer (pyqt5-tools) version == 5.11.3.1.4 and I am having the version of PyQt5 == 5.12.2. I have made a file in the Qt designer and converted it to the .py file using the command `pyuic5 -x hello.ui -o hello.py`

Comment: I'd double check the size policies. Can you upload a gist of the .ui file?

Comment: I have changed the Question and asked again please check

Comment: Fixed sizes and positions should be avoided as much as possible. Consider using [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead, so that the window and its widget get automatically resized whenever required (what you see in designer might *not* result the same, especially on other computers).

Comment: @pranavmandava I ran the .py that you uploaded using the same version of pyqt and measured the dialog at 400x300, just as you had specified in the .ui file. See screenshot : https://imgur.com/kIlpWy6